# Formatting Message arguments

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

Can anyone explain why the first of these expressions works as expected while the second does not? What is the difference between `"number one"` and `DisplayForm@"number one"`?

```
Block[{$MessagePrePrint}, Message[f::event, DisplayForm@"number one"]]

Block[{$MessagePrePrint}, Message[f::event, "number one"]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is a clue:

> An unknown box name (Times) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression.

I presume `$MessagePrePrint` is low level, like `$PreRead`, and its output needs to be a valid box structure.

Comment: So we can use `ToBoxes` instead of `DisplayForm`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Doesn't happen on my machine. See my answer.

Comment: @Alexey, Yes.  Again it is hard for me to understand what you are doing, so pardon me if I am trivializing a difficult issue.  You can use `Block[{$MessagePrePrint = Automatic} ...` if you just want to temporarily disable a custom `$MessagePrePrint`.

Comment: In really I do not like to change global *Mathematica* settings and use modified functions only *inside* my own where I can control their behavior. In this particular case I just don't see any need in `$MessagePrePrint` inside my function at all. So I disable it.

Comment: Instead of `"number one"` I write now `"\"number one\""`. It works. :)

Comment: @Alexey If I understand you do not want some other setting to be active inside your own program.  Use `$MessagePrePrint = Automatic` to disable an external setting, as according to the help file, that is the default.  edit: interesting that you can escape the string delimiters, but I stand by my recommendation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I'm guessing that Alexey is being really careful with all of this because of his work with MathLink...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard As I have already said I think there is no need for `$MessagePrePrint` inside my program at all. And `$MessagePrePrint = Automatic` I do not need too since I do not know exactly how it works and even in that case I would probably not use it because I just do not need any additional preprocessing of `Message` arguments.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `"\"number one\""` is just the output of `"number one"//ToBoxes//FullForm`.

Answer (score 2):

Works on my machine (v8.0.1, W7-64):

[image]

Comment: I like the message text you chose.

Comment: I use *Mathematica* 7.0.1. So we see another one innovation in v. 8.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard How did I know you'd recognize it?   ;-)